# How to copy many files within Windows LAN through ssh fast

Tags: windows, ssh, network-share, copy

In a remote LAN I want to copy (not move) a set of ca. 5000 (already zipped) files, in sum 30 GB, between 2 directories (storage, connected as drive letters by *net use*) regularly, but only after checking the list of files from a computer connected to this LAN via *ssh*.
Using WinSCP or similar tools takes about 2 h to copy the file set, while via Remote Desktop and using Windows' Explorer copy & paste takes good 30 min only.
This seems to be a protocol issue (e.g. directory listing may take half a minute). Zipping (without compression as the 5000 files are compressed already) to transfer just one file brings WinSCP down to this 30 min, but zip/unzip eats the time saved for transfer.

Given I want to copy through *ssh* and not install additional tools on remote side: What alternatives do I have to get this 30 min speed?
*xcopy* would be an option, but I'm asking for starting copy function of Explorer or very similar on command line.
What is the appropriate approach for large number of file using Windows standard tools / possibilities only (that can be started via ssh)?

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd be looking at leveraging the existing [Background Intelligent Transfer Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service) built into windows (XP and better).

I've not used it, but it does seem like it should be a good fit for what you want to do.

Comment: thanks, good hint, was not aware off this.
In my case I'd like to get more or less full bandwidth.
From 1st look you seem to need to tell every file explicitly -- have the list, still xcopy (just tell source directory) seems more appropriate here.

Comment: I suspect that somewhere there's a util (3rd party) that'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use nc (netcat) as she doesn't have such overhead like a ssh (winscp)